# Mongoose conditional required validation

Tags: validation, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and trying to set a custom validation that tells the property shall be required (ie. not empty) if another property value is set to something. I'm using the code below:

```
thing: {
type: String,
validate: [
    function validator(val) {
        return this.type === 'other' && val === '';
    }, '{PATH} is required'
]}
```

- If I save a model with `{"type":"other", "thing":""}` it fails correctly.
- If I save a model with `{"type":"other", "thing": undefined}` or `{"type":"other", "thing": null}` or `{"type":"other"}` the validate function is never executed, and "invalid" data is written to the DB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of mongoose 3.9.1, you can pass a function to the `required` parameter in the schema definition.  That resolves this problem.

See also the conversation at mongoose: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/941

Answer (score 5):

For whatever reason, the Mongoose designers decided that custom validations should not be considered if the value for a field is `null`, making conditional required validations inconvenient. The easiest way I found to get around this was to use a highly unique default value that I consider to be "like null".

```
var LIKE_NULL = '13d2aeca-54e8-4d37-9127-6459331ed76d';

var conditionalRequire = {
  validator: function (value) {
    return this.type === 'other' && val === LIKE_NULL;
  },
  msg: 'Some message',
};

var Model = mongoose.Schema({
  type: { type: String },
  someField: { type: String, default: LIKE_NULL, validate: conditionalRequire },
});

// Under no condition should the "like null" value actually get persisted
Model.pre("save", function (next) {
  if (this.someField == LIKE_NULL) this.someField = null;

  next()
});
```

A complete hack, but it has worked for me so far.

Comment: This is the only solution pre mongoose 3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this validation to the `type` attribute, then adjust your validation accordingly. E.g.:

```
function validator(val) {
  val === 'other' && this.thing === '';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
thing: {
    type: String,
    required: function()[{
        return this.type === 'other';
    }, 'YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MSG HERE']
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?