# How to construct a custom validator that makes a MongoDB field required if another field is a particular value?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB and Mongoose.

Suppose I have the following Schema.

```
const notificationMetaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    listingId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
});

const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: { type: String, required: true, enum: [ "categoryA", "categoryB" ] },
    meta: notificationMetaSchema,
});
```

I want my "listingId" field to be required only when the "category" field is "categoryA".

This validation ideally exists during both document creation and updates.

**How do I construct a custom validator to achieve this effect?**

**EDIT**

I have tried the following:

```
const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    category: { type: String, required: true, enum: [ "categoryA", "categoryB" ] },
    meta: {
        listingId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: function () {
                return [
                    "categoryA",
                ].includes(this.category);
            }
        },
    },
});
```

**However, when I call the following query:**

```
Notification.findOneAndUpdate({}, $set: { category: "categoryA", meta: {} }).exec();
```

No validation error is thrown

Comment: so, you want meta property be required. Right?

Comment: I want the “listing” field in the meta property to be required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose conditional required validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732836/mongoose-conditional-required-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a javaScript function for a field in mongoose schema, that function can act as custom validator, Your schema should look like :

```
const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["categoryA", "categoryB"]
  },
  meta: {
    listingId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: function checkRequiredOrNot() {
        /** This function returns true or false, 'this.category' will retrieve current object's 'category' value */
        return this.category == "categoryA" ? true : false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I gave your solution a shot; however, I didn't see an error get thrown when I made an invalid error so I'm not sure what's going on. (refer to my edited post for more details).

Comment: @user8888 : It will work perfectly with `.save()` but in general `required` itself won't work like expected in calls like `.findOneAndUpdate()`, Check this ref :(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101984/mongoose-findoneandupdate-and-runvalidators-not-working). Since in your case you don't have direct `required`,So even during `$unset` it doesn't work,As to make `required` work you need `category` value which doesn't exist in updates,Use `pre-hook` if not Last thing I can suggest is to use `.save()` if nothing else can be done or use some packages as suggested there or a joi validation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. Just out of curiosity for my own learning / understanding. Is there anyway of achieving your solution by having a separate "meta" schema (as shown in my original post)? I'm guessing no because "this" would be referring to the "meta" schema instead of the "notification" schema?

Comment: @user8888 : Yes correct `this` refers to current schema, So you need to wrap meta inside original schema itself, There maybe any other options that I don't know, but so far these are the options that we've & I know :-)